# Should I should use 'to' or 'for' in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions, for

> Could you please provide admin credentials **to** me and Sandy **for** feel free to add a new user or change?

and the second one

> Could you please provide admin credentials **to** us **for** feel free to add a new user or change?

Am I using to and for properly here?
What should I use? And what is the rule?

Comment: I agree with Davo - **for** just doesn't make any sense there.  I'm not sure what you're trying to say with the last part of the sentence.

Comment: Can you explain why you say for feel free? Do you mean: so we can feel free to add a new user or change the user?  Your use of FOR is wrong. It should be: so we can feel, as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please provide admin credentials to **Sandy and me**

Change the order from *me and Sandy* to *Sandy and me* and add a period (**.**), and this is a proper sentence.

> Could you please provide admin credentials to us

Add a period (**.**), and this is a proper sentence.

I don't understand what you mean by the rest:

> ...for feel free to add a new user or change?

Comment: Thanks. I want to tell him about the reason why I need credentials. To feel free for create a new user and change user.

Comment: ... so that we will be able to add and edit users.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide admin credentials to us **so that we can** feel free to add a new user or change?

If you use 'for' here, then you'll have to change feel to feeling, which will be incorrect usage of the idiom- feel free.